# Evaluate recommender system based on profit margin generated?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, predictive-models, model-evaluation, recommender-system

Let's say that I have two recommendation system models built,  Model A and Model B.

Now I track the performance of both the models for 5 days from 1st Jan to 5th Jan.

Each model has been assigned a different number of users to test the performance each day.

We capture metrics like as shown below. Now, how can I know which model performs better?

[image]

Now which of these two models perform better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one that earns more money, although I’m not sure if profit margin is the best metric in here as it depends on factors not related to the model.

For example, say that one model recommends expensive products, that have high production costs etc, like cars, another model recommends paperclips, with very low production costs etc. I personally would prefer to sell a car, even if I only got a small percentage of the selling price, than a paperclip, even if I could get nearly 100% of the selling price for myself.

Another problem is the [Goodhart’s Law](https://www.fast.ai/2019/09/24/metrics/). If you optimize for profit margin you may end up with recommending only the items with low taxes. If you optimized for money that you earned, you may end up with recommending only the expensive items. In general, using business metrics for evaluation is a good idea, but it is worth to consider consequences. For example, if you only recommend expensive items, you may discourage part of your customers from your website. “But we earned more money.” Yes, though in short run. What if those consumers bought a single expensive product and never came back vs customers that buy less expensive, but regularly? Picking metrics is a tricky business.

Comment: Hi tim, Thanks upvoted.. So, you mean to say that with the above model metrics we cannot conclude which of the model is better? Or we can suggest that based on the above metric, Model B is better (high average margin) but we should also let the stakeholders know the implications of considering different scenarios (such as chances of having customer not come back). So, we can suggest that it's better to capture few more metrics to answer this question effectively. If yes, what are other metrics do you think can be useful?

Comment: Like no of unique customers who purchased, no of items sold under differrnt price ranges, time spent under website,?

Comment: @TheGreat you can suggest any metric and use it to compare models. For example, you could count the number of customers with the letter “z” in the name and use it to choose the best model, however that would not make the model **useful**. This metric will enable you to find “best” model, under a particular definition of “best”, but I’m not sure if this is what you really want to optimize.

Comment: But @Tim, one quick question . without collecting any new data, if I have to suggest which model is better, can I look at consistency (meaning whether day 1 to day 5 readings show an increasing trend). If yes, I can say that model is better than other... Similarly, can I see which model has lowest decrease between day n+1, day n..then I can say that model is better. Similarly, does these metrics make sense (considering we don't intend to collect new data at the moment)...Your suggestions would be helpful

Comment: @TheGreat without knowing details about your data and the experiment it’s hart to comment. You need to ask yourself this.